# Lizmap URL highlight and zoom to feature on layer

Tags: lizmap

I would like to pass an id or searchstring and a layername in the URL when calling Lizmap, so that Lizmap highlights the feature on the specified layer and zooms to it. I read a lot about all the cool features Lizmap aready offers, but I didn't find anything in the well written documentation.

I was thinking about something in that direction:

https://157.xxx.xx.xx/lizmap/index.php/lizmap/service/?repository=lizmap&project=myproject&layer=mylayer&id=feature_id

Does anybody know if its possible or if there is a workaround?

Comment: About the "well written documentation", I suggest you to use the `next` version of the doc, it has been refactored and in a much better shape : https://docs.lizmap.com/next/en/

Comment: Regarding your question, I think it's doesn't exist. You want to have a better permalink, have a look to a open ticket for instance : https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues/371

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the lizmap-javascript-scripts I've found a script from You, that should do exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-javascript-scripts/tree/master/library/tools/zoom_to_feature_at_startup (zoom_to_feature_at_startup). It's not working yet, but the direction is clear.

Comment: After updating to lizmap 3.4.0 the javascript from above:  https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-javascript-scripts/tree/master/library/tools/zoom_to_feature_at_startup (zoom_to_feature_at_startup) works.